# Item do request não está retornando na function em ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação na qual eu não faço a menos ideia como resolver, e muito menos o motivo do problema

Acontece que um índice especificadamente não está retornando no meu request dentro da função jquery

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {texto: text},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui está tudo perfeito!

Porém olha o que retorna no console.log

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro da função ele retorna apenas o array itens, e não o sugestions também,

O certo seria retornar isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei nem como pesquisar isso.

No php não tem nada de mais, apenas os resultados, e depois um json_encode()

```
$return->suggestions= $suggestions->suggestions;
$return->items      = $this->getImagem($produtos);

return json_encode($return);
```

Comment: O que tens no PHP?

Comment: apenas um json encode do que eu mostrei acima, irei colocar ele no post

Comment: já tentou alterar o `$return->items` para outro nome para ver se não é um ajudante do jQuery que faz isso ? por exemplo `$return->produtos`

Comment: Irei fazer a alteração aqui, mas apenas lembrando que o item que não está retornando é o "suggestions" e não o "items

Comment: Experimente fazer isso: var_dump($return); die(); e veja o que lhe retorna.